# Error when installing nuget package from VSTS feed

Tags: c#, nuget, azure-pipelines

I have a build in VSTS which as a first step installs nuget packages from VSTS Feed and fails doing so. Restore works well, but according to nuget [doc](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages) install command provides the latest package from given version range. Restore provides the given version, not the latest, as far as I experienced so far.

Have you already met this issue?

**Update**: I reported this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3862) to the [vsts-tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks) team.

Error message:

```
2016-11-24T13:42:38.8093462Z Feeds used:
2016-11-24T13:42:38.8093462Z   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
2016-11-24T13:42:38.8103475Z   https://sayusiando.../_packaging/.../nuget/v3/index.json
2016-11-24T13:42:38.8103475Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
2016-11-24T13:42:38.8103475Z 
2016-11-24T13:42:39.2778332Z Using credentials from config. UserName: VssSessionToken
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.NuGetProtocolException: An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'C:\a\1\s\src\DigitalLibrary.sln' from source 'DigitalLibraryNuget'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z    at NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.DependencyInfo.Utils.<LoadResource>d__3.MoveNext()
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z    at NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.DependencyInfo.Utils.<LoadRanges>d__4.MoveNext()
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z    at NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.DependencyInfo.ResolverMetadataClient.<GetDependencies>d__0.MoveNext()
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z    at NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.DependencyInfo.ResolverMetadataClient.<GetRegistrationInfo>d__2.MoveNext()
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1439116Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.DependencyInfoResourceV3.<ResolvePackages>d__5.MoveNext()
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.DependencyInfoResourceV3.<ResolvePackages>d__5.MoveNext()
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<GetLatestVersionCoreAsync>d__65.MoveNext()
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<>c__DisplayClass64_1.<<GetLatestVersionAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<GetLatestVersionAsync>d__64.MoveNext()
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<GetLatestVersionAsync>d__63.MoveNext()
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1449094Z    at NuGet.CommandLine.InstallCommand.<InstallPackage>d__34.MoveNext()
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1699089Z ##[error]Error: C:\a\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.24\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.3.0\NuGet.exe failed with return code: 1
2016-11-24T13:42:40.1699089Z ##[error]Packages failed to install
```

Comment: Generally, nuget restore is the way to go - nuget install doesn't update your project dependencies or run any pre-/post-install scripts in the package. Is there a particular reason you want to use install?

Comment: As I mentioned, according to the nuget doc if allowedVersion is present in the package.config then the higher version of package from that interval will be installed. It is not going to happen with restore. That is the reason why I would like to use it. I want to split my solution to many pieces and develop in isolation. This way I can manage the dependencies between solutions.

I'm going to setup a private nuget server on my machine and POCing out.